# Get Folder Name accessed from other application

Tags: android, directory

I am developing an application in android that creates folders and stores files and images in these folders. Each folder has a list that contains the names of the applications that are permitted to access these files and images. My question is if there is a possibility to get the name of the folders that other applications want to access in my application in order to know if the name of this other application is available on the list of the desired folder! Can anyone help me ??

Comment: Some answeres here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657916/using-sharedpreferences-to-share-data-between-two-separate-android-applications

Answer (score 0):

1. At first you have to create the custom content provider.  on that
   you    have to insert name of the application that can access to
   those    files/folder into database of content provider.
2. And then other application can access the name of those application list by getting client content resolver.

Comment: the content provider is able to encapsulate a specific data in a file explorer?